# Mapping the SunWaves with an Image in Android

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I am trying to map the sun patterns in android to make an app similar to the apple watch face called solar.

I asked around what the best way to do this would be. They said that I would need to calculate the hour and divide that by 24 to get my x access and then take the hour and divid it by the midDay (sun light wise) and that would be my Y.

So thats what I did.

X axis:

```
public float getXPosition(Date dateTime) {

    float time = getTime(dateTime);

    float percentageX = time / 24.0f;
    float xPosition = percentageX * lineImage.getWidth();

    return xPosition;


}
```

Y axis:

```
 public float getYPosition(Date dateTime) {

    float time = getTime(dateTime);
    float midDayTime = getTime(globalVariables.czc.getMidDay());


    float differeceInTime = 12.0f - time; //reverse order from 0-12 (top down) if >1pm
    Log.d("hours: ", "" + time);


    Log.d("midDay", "" + midDayTime);

    if (time >= midDayTime) {
        time %= midDayTime;
        differeceInTime = time;
    }

    float percentageY = differeceInTime / midDayTime;

    float yPosition = percentageY * lineImage.getHeight();

    return yPosition;
}
```

Then I just mapped the coordinates as so:

```
 public void moveSun() {

    Date dt = new Date();

    sunImage.setY(getYPosition(dt) - sunImage.getHeight() / 2.5f);
    sunImage.setX(getXPosition(dt) - sunImage.getWidth() / 2.5f);

}
```

This is for the sun. 
I have other dots, representing other point in time for the suns movements that have been placed on the map as well.

[image]

As you can see the sun is almost on the line, and some of the dots are on the line. but most are not.

Does anyone know why or how I can fix this?

Maybe a better way to implement the idea.

Is it because this is a wave and not a grid?

Thanks!

**EDIT: This is what happened when I change it to /midday**

```
    if (time < midday) {
        percentageX = time / midday + 0.0f;
        xPosition = percentageX * lineImage.getWidth() + 0.0f;
    }else{
        time -=midday;
        percentageX = time / 24.0f- midday;
        xPosition = percentageX * lineImage.getWidth()+ 0.0f;

    }
```

[image]

Comment: as far I can see, you can exclude the y-position as the cause of your problem. This seems to work, so you have to possible reasons: 1. the x-position is calculated wrong and 2. the sun wave image in the background is not correct. Are you sure the image is correct?

Comment: hey, what do you mean by correct? I took an Image of line and I stretched it out to be the size of the screen, should I have left it the size it was?

Comment: I tried all types of scaling and none of them really worked. sometimes, the sun and dots were even placed out of the image. Which is weird, because all of the x,y positions should be with in the image. Also, I realized a small issue. that when X is being calculated it is being calculated out of 24. so 12 would be the middle of the wave. how ever, this isnt true, midday should be the middle. I tried something else, I will update my question, but the dots and sun went crazy.

Comment: sorry, I have no knowledge about calculating the sun´s "run", so I can´t say anything about your calculation.